# Returning a concatenated list for matching criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of requirements matched to the projects in a matrix-like structure, below.

```
         PJ 1 PJ2  PJ3  ...
Req 1     x    x     x
Req 2     x          x    
Req 3     x    x 
 ...
```

In another sheet, I have the list of requirements (not in the same order). In the column next to these requirements, I would like to return the PJs that have matched with "x". So results should look like this:

```
Req 1: Pj1 PJ2 PJ3
Req 2: PJ1 PJ3
Req 3: PJ1 PJ2
```

Any suggestion on how to get these projects as a horizontal list next to requirements, without gaps in between?

Comment: Try using this: `=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(B$1:D$1,TOROW(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(($F2=$A$2:$A$4)*($B$2:$D$4="x")),{1;1;1}))))` where `B$1:D$1` is the header, `$A$2:$A$4` is the requirement, `$B$2:$D$4` are the x in Sheet 1 and `F2` is the requirements in other sheets. The output will return in single cell and delimited by comma

Comment: Do you want the results for each row in a single cell or in separate cells?

Comment: @TomSharpe yes a single cell would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Answer]

My approach is in **F6** cell

=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(E6,$A$2:$A$4,FALSE),1,,3)="x",$B$1:$D$1,""))

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your requirements correctly, then the output should be like this

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G2`

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(B$1:D$1,TOROW(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(($F2=$A$2:$A$4)*($B$2:$D$4="x")),{1;1;1}))))
```

---

Or, may be using `MAP()` Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G6`

```
=MAP(F6:F8,LAMBDA(m,
CONCAT(FILTER(B1:D1,TOROW(MMULT(
TRANSPOSE((A2:A4=m)*(B2:D4="x")),{1;1;1}))))))
```

---

### EDIT

Here is an update to the existing formula to make it dynamic, also I have created a custom and reusable formula which can be used in any worksheet within the same workbook using the following formula.

[image]

---

• Formula used:

```
=LAMBDA(_SheetOneData,_SheetTwoReq,
LET(_range,_SheetOneData,
_req,DROP(TAKE(_SheetOneData,,1),1),
_data,DROP(_SheetOneData,1,1),
_header,DROP(TAKE(_SheetOneData,1),,1),
_reqOther,FILTER(_SheetTwoReq,_SheetTwoReq<>""),
MAP(_reqOther,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,
FILTER(_header,TOROW(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((m=_req)*(_data="x")),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_SheetTwoReq),,1,0))),""))))))(A1:F5,F7:F10)
```

---

Using a `LAMBDA()` Function to create a **custom**, **reusable function** and refer them by a **friendly name**

```
=RETURN.LIST(A1:F5,F7:F10)
```

---

Where, `LAMBDA()` Function used in **Name Manager** with a **Defined Name** as `RETURN.LIST()` with syntax as

[image]

---

[image]

---

From the screen-print above you can see, you have to enter or extend the range for both data.

[image]

---

One more alternative way of using `MAP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H7`

```
=LAMBDA(_SheetOneData,_SheetTwoReq,
LET(_range,_SheetOneData,
_req,DROP(TAKE(_range,,1),1),
_data,DROP(_range,1,1),
_header,DROP(TAKE(_range,1),,1),
MAP(_SheetTwoReq,LAMBDA(m,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,
FILTER(_header,INDEX(_data,XMATCH(m,_req))="x",""))))))(A1:F5,F7:F10)
```

---

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, these formulas only work with 3x3 data like the sample used; however, if I extend either Req or PJ +1 in the range, I get a value error.

Comment: @ElvinIbishli please refer above I have updated.

Comment: @ElvinIbishli while in the last formula you had to change only this part: `=MAP(F7:F10,LAMBDA(m,CONCAT(FILTER(B1:F1,TOROW(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((A2:A5=m)*(B2:F5="x")),SEQUENCE(ROWS(F7:F10),,1,0)))))))` the `{1;1;1}`

Answer (score 1):

Like Tom Sharp asked: *Do you want the results for each row in a single cell or in separate cells?*

I decided on posting a variation on solutions you may want.

(For each solution I created a dynamic way of dealing with your range. If the range changes, all you need to update is the (full) range in the formula; the rest will adopt to this range):

**BYROW (1)**

```
=LET(range, A1:E6,
     req,   DROP(TAKE(range,,1),1),
     PJ,    DROP(TAKE(range,1),,1),
     data,  DROP(range,1,1),
res,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(PJ,x="x","")))),
HSTACK(req,res))
```

This solution makes use of BYROW to be able to use TEXTJOIN row-wise.
The `Req` data is in the first column and the byrow/textjoin result in the next column.

**BYROW (2)**

```
=LET(range, A1:E6,
     req,   DROP(TAKE(range,,1),1),
     PJ,    DROP(TAKE(range,1),,1),
     data,  DROP(range,1,1),
res,BYROW(data,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(PJ,x="x","")))),
req&": "&res)
```

Does the same as the BYROW (1)-solution, however the `Req` is joined in front of the row-wise textjoin result.

**REDUCE**

```
=LET(Range, A1:E6,
     Req,   DROP(TAKE(Range,,1),1),
     PJ,    DROP(TAKE(Range,1),,1),
     data,  DROP(Range,1,1),
Res,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Req)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,FILTER(PJ,INDEX(data,y,)="x","")))),""),1),
HSTACK(Req,Res))
```

This solution allows you to spill the results to the right. Each result has it's own cell, filtering out the non-"x" values per row.

[image]

Edit: this would show the results as defined in your comment:

```
=LET(range, A1:E6,
     req,   DROP(TAKE(range,,1),1),
     PJ,    DROP(TAKE(range,1),,1),
     data,  DROP(range,1,1),
BYROW(data,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(PJ,x="x","")))))
```

Edit 2: to join results matching the (possibly shuffled) ReqRes (Change C24:C26 to your range containing Req values to be used for the results order):

```
=LET(Range,  A1:E6,
     ReqRes, C24:C26,
     Req,    DROP(TAKE(Range,,1),1),
     PJ,     DROP(TAKE(Range,1),,1),
     data,   DROP(Range,1,1),
DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,C24:C26,LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,FILTER(PJ,INDEX(data,XMATCH(y,Req))="x",""))))),""),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @P.b; this works; however, the solution you provided also returns the list of requirements themselves; since I already have this list, I would just want to return the PJs next to it; they need to match to right requirement. 

And for the question above, I like to return results in one cell rather than each in individual ones.

Comment: The question appeared as if that was required. Please see edit

Comment: Thanks, @P.b for the updated solution; this removes the requirements and only returns PJs, which is what I wanted, however, it still returns results in the same order as a data source, and doesn't match the order I have for requirements in results sheet.

Comment: Gotcha, See edit 2 - This requires two ranges to possibly be changed: 1) `Range` if it expands; 2) `ReqRes` the Range where you keep your `Req`-values to be used for showing the results